# Node js not returning proper result?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this node js program which should return asked variable in the console but it is returning undefined here is code and the input i have trying to parse :-

```
router.post('/createorder',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.ProductName);

    // var obj=JSON.parse(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

the input :

```
{
  "ProductName":"Wine",
  "ProductPrice":"500",
  "ProductQuantity":"2",
  "ProductCost":"1000",
  "SellerId":"2"  
}
```

and here is the main module i'm using

```
var express= require('express');
var routes=require('./routes/api');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'nodemysql'
})
//setting up express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.use(routes);

//listen for requests
/*app.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log('get trial method called');
    res.send({name:'Atul'});
});*/
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('server started on port 3000 ');
});
```

i want to acess an specific object in order to store in the database?

Comment: You are most likely not using the bodyParser middleware.

Comment: It's not mandatory to use the bodyParser middleware, but it would be useful to see the rest of the code to understand it better.

Comment: i' using it in the main module but not in routes module does that causes problem?

Comment: If you're using it in the main module, you shouldn't have problems no, assuming you're using expressJS (or similar) and properly setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

As soueuls mentioned in the comments, you need to make sure express can parse the body of the request as it doesn't do this by default. Assuming you are using express framework. You could have something like this.

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Now you can read the body.

notice if you console log your req object before you add in the code above, you will not see the body property.

UPDATE

this is what i have in my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

In my routes/index.js i have the following

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/createorder',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);

    // var obj=JSON.parse(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

i tested this with postman app and it works.

Comment: i have done what you suggested but still i'm getting the same result

Comment: Could you please show us your code, i will be happy to assist you until you get it working :) . Are you using express?

Comment: Check my amended post

Comment: yeah if i want to read specific data like product name and store in database?

Comment: Sorry, your original question was that you were getting undefined in your post route for the body.req property. I hope my replies were useful but i'm not going to implement a database for you over github. There are plenty of resources showing how to do so.

Comment: my problem is iam not able to acess specific entity in the request

Comment: Yes, and the code in my answer shows how to setup the post route properly. You need the body parser middleware in order for express to expose the body variable. have you checked that you are posting json to your route correctly?

Comment: don't bother got the answer

Comment: what was the answer?

Comment: i was trying to parse json array intead of json objects

Comment: No where in your route are you trying to parse an array of json objects. I assume you had some database or controller for a database you didn't show in your original post.